# Webpack / Babel / Karma does not complain if test files are invalid

Tags: karma-runner, webpack, babeljs

How do I make webpack and karma fail on babel transpiling errors?

Pretty standard setup loading test files like so:

```js
var context = require.context('./app', true, /\.test\.js$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);
```

Given I have these two test:

```js
describe('Success', () => {
    it('should pass', () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(true)
    });
});
```

and

```js
describe('Failure', () => {
    it('should fail', () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(false)
    });
});
```

Then all works well:

```js
Suites and tests results:

- Failure :
  * should fail : failed
- Success :
  * should pass : ok

Browser results:
 - PhantomJS 1.9.8: 2 tests
 - 1 ok, 1 failed
```

BUT if I invalidate the failing test (removing the closing brackets from the Describe call):

```js
describe('Failure', () => {
    it('should fail', () => {
        expect(true).toEqual(false)
    });
```

Then rather than getting a break I just get:

```js
Suites and tests results:

- Success :
 * should pass : ok

Browser results:

 - PhantomJS 1.9.8: 1 tests
   - ok
```

It's like the whole test file didn't exist. This is really problematic as with a large test suite an accidental keystroke in a random test file can cause the whole test to be ignored and a possibly failing build to succeed.

I tried configuring the setting the bail option to true in my karma.config:

```js
webpack: {
        bail:true,
```

But made no difference.

How do I make webpack and karma fail on babel transpiling errors?

Comment: Perhaps http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#bail? Not actually 100% sure.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks but I tried the bail option (updated the question to make it clear how I tried this) but didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? We're running into the same problem, it's crazy that even with the bail option webpack doesn't fail more noisily.

Comment: Pinging again -- would really love to know if you found a solve for this. Thanks!